# Prestashop module Prestablog return Uncaught Error

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I work on a Prestashop e-commerce and this site must have a page with a blog system where the client post articles to help customers to choose their products.

For that i use the PrestaBlog Module and on the configuration page of this blog module i can set the URL of the blog page, but when i enter the URL of an created page dedicated for that with a slug like "practical-advice", i've got an error when i register this setting (see screenshot -> [first-error-with-custom-slug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPx4H.png))

After that i tried on an fresh installation of Prestashop where i only created the dedicated page i need, renamed "blog" this time (because it's the default setting on the setting page of the blog module), and after that i install this module PrestBlog, and i acces the url exemple.fr/blog. And now i've got a new error on a white page (see screenshot the error bellow)

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'prestablogblogModuleFrontController' not found in /var/www/vhosts/exemple.fr/httpdocs/classes/controller/Controller.php:233 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/exemple.fr/httpdocs/classes/Dispatcher.php(510): ControllerCore::getController('prestablogblogM...') #1 /var/www/vhosts/exemple.fr/httpdocs/index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/exemple.fr/httpdocs/classes/controller/Controller.php on line 233`

Currently i can't find where is the problem. I hope somebody can help me.

Thank's

Comment: The error is quite clear, class not found... So a module file may be missing or there may be a programming error or, I guess, a missing override files not properly installed.
Best thing would be contacting the author of the module so he can provide proper support.

Comment: Hi, effectively i contact the developper, and it was a version problem of the plugin. the 4.4.6 solved the problem.